# php Apc caching or File caching for semi-static website?

Tags: php, caching, apc

i'm new in PHP and want to try caching(for the first time), so i make website and  it has :

- dynamic home page
- dynamic portfolio page
- dynamic contact page
- static about page
- static admin page

so i read the tutorial about caching and i try to make my own caching system:

using file cache based on the what page is requested, when the page is requested the cache system will check if there's cache in `cache directory` if there's no cache file yet then write all the output(html) from the php script(in this case output from `output buffer`) and if there's cache file that corresponds with the specific id(based on URI) then just `include_once()` the html file.

Then i read in CodeIgniter(i make this website using CI) says there's APC for caching, then i read again about APC, what i read about APC is that it caches the DB results, but now i'm confused which should i use

what i get so far:

- file caching probably would slower if there's alot of request (i dont know if this is true or not but i read it somewhere from search engine)
- APC is fast

but i'm still confused which i should use , i'm on shared hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The levels of caching most relevant in a PHP application:

- **File / Script caching** - The operating system will actually do this to a large extent. When a file is opened it's added to an OS-level cache. It stays there until the file is touched or the OS needs to free memory for other processes. *A homegrown PHP solution isn't a good replacement for this.*
- **Opcode caching** - In order to function, PHP needs to parse and compile a script into opcodes. A mechanism like APC will cache the opcodes of every PHP script executed by Apache, provided that the cache doesn't overflow. *A homegrown PHP solution build on top of APC can **partially** do this, but APC already does it ... so don't bother.*
- **Query caching** - If your script accesses a lot of data that doesn't change very frequently, or wherein some latency between updates and the visibility of those updates is acceptable, caching the results from *complex* queries is beneficial. *A homegrown PHP solution built on APC is acceptable and beneficial at this level. But a database level solution is also appropriate here, and often **more** appropriate.*
- **Output caching** - If your page is largely deterministic and/or the same sort of latency applicable to *query caching* is acceptable, you can cache the entire output of the script using output buffering and APC. *A homegrown PHP solution built on APC is acceptable here, but generally not necessary.* If the page is static, you're probably not saving yourself any re-computation. And if it's dynamic, it's *usually* preferable to just re-render the page anyway.

In a dedicated or virtual-dedicated environment you'd need install APC (or something similar) yourself. But, in a shared hosting environment, it's very likely that APC is installed. And if it weren't you couldn't install it yourself anyway.

And, due to my own uncertainty, I'd recommend *not* performing any query or output caching with APC in a shared environment -- I'm not sure whether APC segregates caches by virtual host. Even if it does, I wouldn't assume that my site is truly a separate virtual host.

Comment: hi there thx for your answer, i just checked my shared host and i confirm it doesn't have `APC` installed :( so maybe i'm thinking to fallback to simple file caching i made (which stores the outputs(html) from `output buffer`) what do you think about it? should i cache it? because the portfolio page will get many images `URI` from DB and echoing it in `<img src="" />`

Comment: @mohur It's nearly impossible to make a reasonable recommendation with so little information. I'd say, don't prematurely optimize. If you start to see performance problems, your first step should be to move off shared hosting!

Comment: so for now i shouldn't cache it right? and if it does have problem, then i just move shared hosting? i mean now i get the point, even if i implement caching, it wouldnt affect much because on shared hosting, all the website is on 1 server right? (i.e another user on shared hosting got heavy DOS'ed then the server will overload and my caching wouldnt even work) sorry for the long question because of my curiosity, :D

Comment: You can certainly perform query or output caching if a particular request is long-running.  But, without an in-memory caching mechanism, you're caching to disk. So, the gain is reduced by seek latency, which can tend to be disproportionately high with respect to traffic on shared hosts.

Comment: @mohur Point being, in a shared environment, you probably want to cache only those requests that already border on the edge of acceptability for execution time to begin with. To support a greater load or for any truly advanced caching, you need reliable *in-memory* caching, which often means virtual or dedicated hosting ... and possibly some more, specific professional guidance.

Comment: sorry but i don't get the term of 'request is long-running', does it mean the server process the script for like n seconds(needs long time to process the script due to some problems) ? ok thanks for the clear answer, maybe i'll just do output caching and delete the cache file if something is updated.

Comment: @mohur Sorry, I completed that thought over the span of two comments. But, in essence, my recommendation for a site on a shared host: If the *visible* load time for a particular page is unacceptable, see if query and/or output caching helps, provided that a move to non-shared hosting isn't a viable first step.

Comment: yeah thankyou very much for your help :D that clears my mind and make me more understand about the problem im having